# Paypal Express Checkout: Missing Login Form and Payment Button in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I was successfully checking out orders before on Paypal's Sandbox. Today, the login form and the button to complete the payment suddenly fail to display. Anybody encountered this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the many random browser cookie issues that PayPal's servers tend to have.  I'd suggest logging out of any sandbox or live PayPal accounts you might be in, then completely close your browser out, open it up and try again.